Configure multiple search-base-dn paths for ldap-realm
I'm trying to configure the ldap-realm, to search the user in multiple paths. The example configuration is:
./subsystem=elytron/ldap-realm=ldap-realm:add(dir-context=ldap-connection, \
direct-verification=true, \
identity-mapping={search-base-dn="ou=users,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org", \
rdn-identifier="uid", \
attribute-mapping=[{filter-base-dn="ou=groups,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org",filter="(uniqueMember={1})",from="uid",to="Roles"}]})

The idea is to configure ldap-realm to search for the credentials not just on ou=users,dc=group-to-principal,dc=wildfly,dc=org, but also in other paths.
I tried creating an array for identity-mapping, with multiple configurations, but this wasn't accepted.
I also tried creating multiple ldap-realms, and aggregating them with an aggregate-realm, but it also didn't work.
I also tried using only the top of the path, where they split (dc=wildfly,dc=org, for example), but JBoss didn't find the user.
Does anyone have an example on how to configure multiple paths for the search-base-dn?
